# How can I pass a ML value as an argument to an outer syntax command?

Tags: isabelle

I define an outer syntax command, `imake` to write some code to a file and do some other things. The intended usage is as follows:

```
theory Scratch
imports Complex_Main "~/Is0/IsS"
begin
  imake ‹myfile›
end
```

The above example will write some contents to the file `myfile`. `myfile` should be a path relative to the location of the `Scratch` theory.

```
ML ‹val this_path = File.platform_path(Resources.master_directory @{theory})
```

I would like to be able to use the value `this_path` in specifying `myfile`. The `imake` command is defined in the import `~/Is0/IsS` and currently looks as follows:

```
ML‹(*imake*)
val _ = Outer_Syntax.improper_command @{command_spec "imake"} ""
  (Parse.text >> 
    (fn path => Toplevel.keep 
      (fn _ => Gc.imake path)))›
```

The argument is pased using `Parse.text`, but I need feed it the path based on the ML value `this_path`, which is defined later (in the `Scratch` theory). I searched around a lot, trying to figure out how to use something like `Parse.const`, but I won't be able to figure anything out any time soon.

So: It's important that I use, in some way, `Resources.master_directory @{theory}` in `Scratch.thy`, so that `imake` gets the folder `Scratch` is in, which will come from the use of `@{theory}` in `Scratch`.

If I'm belaboring the last point, it's because in the past, I wasted a lot of time getting the wrong folder, because I didn't understand how to use the command above correctly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you want to define the imake command first and then have it depend on a ML value you set later on in a (maybe another) theory?

Comment: @Lars, what you show below looks like it should be the thing, though I haven't tried it yet. I go ahead and show a minimal theory. Doing it your way will get rid of an argument. I'm on U.S. time, so I have to sleep for a little while before I work on things some more. Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to use the master_directory, you can compute the path inside the imake command, too. The function you give to Toplevel.keep takes as argument (which ignore currently) a Toplevel.state, which contains a context and therefore also a theory. I'll expand my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'd like to add that `Parse.const` is not for parsing values referring to ML constants (which cannot be done; at least not in a remotely sane way), but for parsing constants of the Isar outer grammar.

Comment: @Lars, I got part of it working. Thanks for the technical pointers, such as the type of `Toplevel.keep`. I've been modifying Makarius' examples from the past, and I got lucky in getting a command working yesterday, because I was making changes, but not paying attention to that. Knowing that helped me to modify things here. In the source I put below, I show that the ML commands don't set the configuration option `imake_path`. The part that works is good, and will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your minimal examples uses `Resource.master_directory` with the parameter `@{theory}` to define your path. `@{theory}` refers (statically) to the theory at the point where you write down the antiquotation. This is mostly for interactive use, when you explore stuff. For code which is used in other places, you must use the dynamically passed context and extract the theory from it.

The function `Toplevel.keep` you use takes a function `Toplevel.state -> unit` as an argument. The Toplevel.state contains a context (see chapter 1 of the [Isabelle Implementation Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/implementation.pdf)), which again contains the current theory; with `Toplevel.theory_of` you can extract the theory from the state. For example, you could use

```
Toplevel.keep (fn state => writeln
  (File.platform_path (Resources.master_directory (Toplevel.theory_of state))))
```

to define a command that prints the master_directory for your current theory.

Except in simple cases, it is very likely that you do not only need the theory, but the whole context (which you can get with `Toplevel.context_of`).

### Use setup from preceding (parts of the) theory

In the previous section, I assumed that you always want to use the master directory. For the case where the path should be configurable, Isabelle knows the concept of *configuration options*.

In your case, you would need to define an configuration option before you declare your `imake` command

```
ML ‹
  val imake_path = Attrib.setup_config_string @{binding imake_path}
      (K path)
› (* declares an option imake_path with the value `path` as default value *)
```

Then, the imake command can refer to this attribute to retrieve the path via `Config.get`:

```
Toplevel.keep (fn state =>
   let val path = Config.get (Toplevel.context_of state) imake_path
   in ... end)
```

The value of `imake_path` can then be set in Isar (only as a string):

```
declare [[imake_path="/tmp"]]
```

or in ML, via `Config.map` (for updating proof contexts) or `Config.map_global` (for updating theories). Note that you need to feed the updated context back to the system. Isar has the command `setup` (takes an ML expression of type `theory -> theory`) for that:

```
setup ‹Config.map_global imake_path (K "/tmp")›
```

Configuration options are described in detail in the [Isar Implementation Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/implementation.pdf), section 1.1.5.

**Note**: This mechanism does *not* allow you to automatically set `imake_path` to the master directory for each new theory. You need to set it manually, e.g. by adding

```
setup ‹
Config.map imake_path
  (K (File.platform_path (Resources.master_directory @{theory})))
›
```

at the beginning of each theory.

The more general mechanism behind configuration options is *context data*. For details, see section 1.1 and in particular section 1.1.4 of the [Isabelle Implementation Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/implementation.pdf)). This mechanism is used in a lot of places in Isabelle; the `simpset`, the configuration of the simplifier, is one example for this.