# Trying to define custom 'declare' & 'using' commands

Tags: isabelle

I figure out how to modify some Isar and ML, but here I don't know how to get what I want.

I use `declare` and `using` to turn info on and off, like with these (and other longer combinations):

```
declare[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]
declare[[show_sorts=false]]
using[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]
using[[show_sorts=false]]
```

I've created jEdit macros to temporarily insert big long `declare` and `using` commands, but one problem is that I can forget to remove them.

What I want to do is define `declare` and `using` commands that don't take an argument. Additionally, these commands would use `Output.warning` so that I know to remove them.

For example, I would define keywords like the following, which would correspond to the 4 commands above:

```
keywords 
  "simpD" "~sortsD" :: thy_decl
and
  "simpU" "~sortsU" :: prf_decl % "proof"
```

From [src/Pure/Isar/isar_syn.ML#l229](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/Pure/Isar/isar_syn.ML#l229) and [src/Pure/Isar/isar_syn.ML#l588](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/Pure/Isar/isar_syn.ML#l588), I find the `declare` and `using` commands:

```
val _ = Outer_Syntax.local_theory' @{command_spec "declare"} "declare theorems"
  (Parse.and_list1 Parse_Spec.xthms1 -- Parse.for_fixes
    >> (fn (facts, fixes) =>
        #2 oo Specification.theorems_cmd "" [(Attrib.empty_binding, flat facts)] fixes));

val _ = Outer_Syntax.command @{command_spec "using"} "augment goal facts"
  (facts >> (Toplevel.proof o Proof.using_cmd));
```

Below, I include a short theory to show how the commands would be used. I define outer syntax for `simpD` and `simpU`, using dummy commands, that show partly what I want. The dummy commands take an argument, but I don't want that. I want a command like `help`, which takes no arguments.

Thanks.

```
theory i150312a__custom_declare_and_using_syntax
imports Complex_Main
keywords 
  "simpD" "~sortsD" :: thy_decl
and
  "simpU" "~sortsU" :: prf_decl % "proof"
begin
(*Want outer syntax for fixed 'declare' (and 'using') commands like these.*)
declare[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]
declare[[show_sorts=false]]

(*EXE: declare[[simp_trace_new mode=full]] with a warning. Please modify as needed.*)
ML{*Outer_Syntax.improper_command @{command_spec "simpD"} ""
  (Parse.text >> (fn _ => Toplevel.keep (fn _ => 
  let
    val _ = Output.warning "DECLARE: declare[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]"
  in () end)))*}

simpD"" (* But here, I don't want to have to use the double quotes.*)

(*EXE: using[[simp_trace_new mode=full]] with a warning. Please modify as needed.*)
ML{*Outer_Syntax.improper_command @{command_spec "simpU"} ""
  (Parse.text >> (fn _ => Toplevel.keep (fn _ => 
  let
    val _ = Output.warning "USING: using[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]"
  in () end)))*}

lemma "True"
  simpU"" (* But here, I don't want to have to use the double quotes.*)
by(simp)

(* FROM src/Pure/Isar/isar_syn.ML
val _ = Outer_Syntax.local_theory' @{command_spec "declare"} "declare theorems"
  (Parse.and_list1 Parse_Spec.xthms1 -- Parse.for_fixes
    >> (fn (facts, fixes) =>
        #2 oo Specification.theorems_cmd 
        "" [(Attrib.empty_binding, flat facts)] fixes));

val _ = Outer_Syntax.command @{command_spec "using"} "augment goal facts"
  (facts >> (Toplevel.proof o Proof.using_cmd));
*)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning myself is the most important thing. Here's what my `WARN` and trace commands look like, inserted with a jEdit macro and key-sequence:

```
lemma "True"
  WARN"trace"using[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]
  WARN"trace"using[[linarith_trace,rule_trace,blast_trace,blast_stats]]
by(blast)
```

I actually use `\<open>` and `\<close>` in place of double quotes, but a cartouche doesn't always get displayed correctly in a browser.

## Setting defaults, getting confused when forgetting about changes

I mostly keep my THYs clear of warnings, so I should notice the amber warning color in the right-hand gutter.

I set my working preferences in an import `i0.thy`, like the following, where some change the defaults, and all tell me explicitly what I should see or not see:

```
declare[[show_sorts=true]]
declare[[show_types=false]]
declare[[show_brackets=false]]
declare[[names_unique=true]]
declare[[show_question_marks=true]]
declare[[show_consts=true]]
...(and more)
```

Most I never change, but `show_sorts`, `show_types`, and `show_brackets` I need to constantly change, sometimes to show me details, and sometimes to get rid of clutter.

I keep the output panel open all the time, and `show_consts` is a major help in seeing how types are inferred, because that's extremely important when trying to instantiate type classes for a type, and important in general.

To keep unnecessary source from being processed, I have to insert the `declare` where I'm working.

Okay, so the problem is that when I insert a show command, and then forget about it, I end up getting confused. I look at what I have set in `i0.thy`, and then can't figure out why I'm not seeing certain details, or am seeing certain details.

## A little explanation about the THY

Below, I include a theory which has the `WARN` command. I also include the jEdit macro, which I have in my *.isabelle/Isabelle2014/jEdit/macros* folder. In jEdit *Global Options / Shortcuts*, I assigned the macro a key-sequence.

Some details:

- The `diag` in `keywords` allows the `WARN` keyword to be used in a proof.
- The `blast_trace` and `blast_stats` are only necessary here because I show the traces I turn on whenever I use `simp_trace_new`.
- The source for `blast_trace` and `blast_stats` came from [M. Wenzel on the isabelle-users mailing list](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/index.html).
- The source for `WARN` is a tweaking of source provided by [L. Noschinski in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841823/how-can-i-pass-a-ml-value-as-an-argument-to-an-outer-syntax-command/25844580#25844580).
- One reason I turn on the other traces is because `auto` sometimes calls other methods, such as `blast`, and even `simp` may call things.
- I sometimes want to know exactly what `simp` rules are being used, and use a command like `apply(simp only: thm1, thm2, ...)` or `apply(auto simp only: thm1, thm2, ...)`. What I've seen in the past is that `blast` or linear arithmetic methods can get called automatically.
- If you want to use `declare` outside of a proof, instead of `using` in a proof, create you a jEdit macro for `declare`.

## The macro

The short part is the jEdit macro:

```
//isar__ust....using_simp_trace.bsh

textArea.setSelectedText("WARN\<open>trace\<close>using[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]");
textArea.insertEnterAndIndent();
textArea.setSelectedText("WARN\<open>trace\<close>using[[linarith_trace,rule_trace,blast_trace,blast_stats]]");
```

I can't remember my key sequences, so I put them in the file name. I use a 4-letter sequence, `ALT-i u s t`.

I use [Q-Dir](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir), to view 4 different folders which contain my jEdit macro files.

## The THY

Here's the THY:

```
theory i150312b__my_WARN
imports Main
keywords "WARN" :: diag
begin
ML{*Outer_Syntax.improper_command @{command_spec "WARN"} 
  "Print a warning message"
  (Parse.text >> (fn s => Toplevel.keep (fn _ => 
    let val _ = Output.warning ("WARNING: " ^ s) in () end)))*}

attribute_setup blast_trace = {*
  Scan.lift
   (Parse.$$$ "=" -- Args.$$$ "true" >> K true ||
    Parse.$$$ "=" -- Args.$$$ "false" >> K false ||
    Scan.succeed true) >>
  (fn b => Thm.declaration_attribute (K (Config.put_generic Blast.trace b)))
*}

attribute_setup blast_stats = {*
  Scan.lift
   (Parse.$$$ "=" -- Args.$$$ "true" >> K true ||
    Parse.$$$ "=" -- Args.$$$ "false" >> K false ||
    Scan.succeed true) >>
  (fn b => Thm.declaration_attribute (K (Config.put_generic Blast.stats b)))
*} 

lemma "True"
  WARN"trace"using[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]
  WARN"trace"using[[linarith_trace,rule_trace,blast_trace,blast_stats]]
by(blast)
end
```

## The Isabelle Cookbook, by Christian Urban, with contributions

I need to find time to work through the Isabelle Cookbook, to be able to tweak and create Isar outer syntax commands. People don't want to work for free, or I burn bridges. The page is [www.inf.kcl.ac.uk/staff/urbanc/Cookbook](http://www.inf.kcl.ac.uk/staff/urbanc/Cookbook/).

The PDF is also in the tar.gz file on the [TUM repository page](http://www4.in.tum.de/~urbanc/cgi-bin/repos.cgi/isabelle-cookbook), which contains the source. Click on the [gz link](http://www4.in.tum.de/%7Eurbanc/cgi-bin/repos.cgi/isabelle-cookbook/archive/tip.tar.gz).